# Interpreting My Flagging History Sidebar

Tags: support, flag-history

I hope this is not a repeat question. I tried searching but couldn't come up with the right search words for this question.

I see the following in the sidebar of my flagging history tab:

[image: flagging history sidebar]

I notice that I have raised 28 helpful flags from my user page, but I see "27 deemed helpful" and "1 deemed helpful". What is the difference between the top half and the bottom half of the entries in the flagging history sidebar? How should I interpret the results displayed in the sidebar?

Comment: Dear close voters, did you read the questions or even look at the screenshots? The "duplicate" is asking about the individual flags, this is about the totals in the sidebar. They're on the same screen, but that's where any similarity ends.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Your total "helpful flags" count:

[image: Total]

## is the sum of your helpful moderator, spam, offensive, and comment flags:

[image: Detail]

## Which map onto the flag dialog thusly:

[image: Flag dialog]

(1*) close flags are only available below 3k rep, when they become close votes.

And comment flags are not from the dialog with the others, they appear when you hover your mouse over a comment below a question or answer:

[image: Comment flag]

Comment: "Thus" is already an adverb.  There's no need to add the suffix *-ly.*

Answer (score 4):

You also have one spam flag deemed helpful. 27 + 1 = 28. The count of helpful flags you see on your profile page is the sum of all helpful flags from the sidebar. The sidebar just presents a more detailed breakdown by flag type.

> What is the difference between the top half and the bottom half of the entries in the flagging history sidebar?

The first block on the sidebar is about flags on questions and answers, except for "spam" and "offensive" flags. Those are displayed in separate blocks below. And below those, there is another block for comment flags.