# Comment(s) flagged in flag summary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flag-history

As I was checking the status of my current flags, I noticed a new entry called "comments flagged". I had last flagged a comment in late February. According to [Interpreting My Flagging History Sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157344/interpreting-my-flagging-history-sidebar), this feature has been in since early December. Is this a feature still being rolled out, or does this depend on *how* the comment was removed (flags vs commentor-deleted)?

Furthermore, I only have one flag outstanding in my flag summary, and it was regarding an answer. Is it being misapplied to the comment flag section?

My current right-side display (as of Mar 13 2013):

```
Your flagging history
xxx moderator attention flags
  1 waiting for review
xxx deemed helpful
xxx declined
xxx disputed

xxx post marked spam
xxx deemed helpful

  1 comment flagged
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag awaiting review is your flag on a possible duplicate question.

Comment flags don't show up in the comment history at all except as a summary on the right.

I believe if the comment is deleted via comment flags, a comment flag will be marked as "helpful". If the flag is dismissed, it will be marked as "declined". If a moderator just deletes the comment, I think that won't have any effect on your flag, but I'm not 100% on that. This seems reasonable, though, considering what you're seeing... unless we still have comment flags sitting around since late February.

Either way, the numbers (1 and 1) are just a coincidence.

Comment: Is this a recent change? When I use the browser search on Chrome, I see three instances of "not an answer" on the first page

Comment: @ChrisForrence Sure, and all of those have a resolution beside them - 2 helpful, 1 declined. The unresolved flag in your summary is proposing a duplicate for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395856/check-length-of-field-is-greater-than-zero).

Comment: Ah. I see my mistake; I was interpreting answer flags as comment flags. I do only have one comment flag